# Joining section in the From clause

Tags: sql, database

Here,I have used joining section in the `from` clause ...

```
select course_id, semester, year, sec_id, avg (tot_cred)
from takes natural join student
where year = 2009
group by course_id, semester, year, sec_id
having count (ID) >= 2
```

Now, My question is , Is this sql query correct ? If yes then why ? Or If not then why ? Thanks.

Comment: Correct for what? select * from a is correct, depend on what you want to achieve!

Answer (score 2):

Your query is *technically* correct.  However, I would advise you strongly to never using `natural join`.  It is a bug waiting to happen.  Why?  It uses the names -- and only the names -- of columns in the underlying tables.  It does not even use declared foreign key relationships.

Instead, use an explicit `on` or `using` clause:

```
select courseid, semester, year, secid, avg(totcred)
from takes t join
     student s
     using (studentid)
where year = 2009
group by courseid, semester, year, secid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Also:

- I assume that the spaces in "course id", "sec id", and "tot cred" are simply typos.
- Use table aliases.
- Qualify the column names -- that is identify what table they are coming from.